# Youtube search api V3 javascript

Tags: javascript, search, youtube, youtube-api, video-processing

Here I have working API request, which can return maximum 50 videos (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) ),
How can I have `more` functionality ?

When I click on `more` button I need to get videos after already returned 50, it means from 50 to 100, for next click from 100 to 150, etc.

```js
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
      "part": "masha i medved",
      "maxResults": 50,
      "q": "surfing"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
       // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
          console.log("Response", response); // returns 50 videos from 1000000 result
    },
    function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response includes the nextPageToken which you would use in your next request parameters to get the next page of results ( see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) ). You can fetch up to 500 search results this way.